# How to monitor the number of SELECT statements to a specific table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

For global I know we can use:

```
show global status like "Com_select";
```

But what about a specific table?

Comment: You can always turn on the general query log and pick through it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Check on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) for server-level questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Another way...

```
 long_query_time = 0
```

and turn on the slowlog.

After some time, use `pt-query-digest` to summarize the slowlog.  It will include counts (and timings) for each similar query.  "Similar" referring to how it "digests" the queries, primarily changing numbers to "N" and strings to "S".  The tablename remains intact, so there will be a small number of queries for a given table, while each type of query may have occurred thousands of times.